# Python PIL text placement centering

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a format certificate, let's assume equal to this: https://elearning.adobe.com/blank-achievement-certificate

Once downloaded the sample certificate and saved as 'certificate.png', I wrote an example code on Python of what I have to do to automate certificates production:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

people = ['Homer Simpson', 'Seymour Skinner', 'Apu Nahasapeemapetilon']
for i in range(len(people)):
    img = Image.open('certificate.png')
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    d.text((290, 210), people[i], fill = (255, 0, 0), font = ImageFont.truetype("times.ttf", 24))
    img.show()
```

I am looking for obtaining a way to center the text to be written along x axis direction, as certificates are not acceptable depending on the length of the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PIL.ImageDraw` has a method to get the size of the text you're about to draw:

```py
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
w, h = draw.textsize("Your Text")
```

so to write something in the center you'd do the following

```py
people = ['Homer Simpson', 'Seymour Skinner', 'Apu Nahasapeemapetilon']
for person in people:
    img = Image.open('certificate.png')

    # Get the size of the image
    W, H = img.size

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    
    # Get the size of the textbox
    w, h = draw.textsize(person)
    
    coords = ((W - w) / 2, (H - h) / 2)
    draw.text(coords, person, fill = (255, 0, 0), font = ImageFont.truetype("times.ttf", 24))
    img.show()
```

Also note that you can iterate directly over people, rather than iterating over `range(len(people))`.